# How would monsters realistically exist in our world?

Tags: biology, evolution, earth-like, fauna, creature-design

How would monsters exist in real life?

**Setting:**

The world is like ours, but with some changes. The geography is as if the tectonic plates did a different thing, the plants are similar but there also new plants. This takes place between 15th-16th century (the Renaissance). So people don't have big weapons to fight with, but they managed to get tricks to deal with monsters. It's a world without magic (doesn't mean weird things can't happen) and everything revolves around science.

**What I want**

I want to get how would they exist in our world and behave.

**Monsters**

I didn't work much on them but they are like the animals with a few exceptions, most of them are bigger than a normal animal but there are small monsters too, they affect everything in the world since they are everywhere, except where humans live (Except for a few of them). But they live mostly in the water and in caves, that makes a big part of the monsters blind, some of them evolved with time. There are mythical monsters like the dragon but they don't have the magic powers they would have in another world.

EDIT:
Sorry for my bad English it is not my main language and for the focus on the question I think I didn't write what I was thinking about, I want to do this by myself but I have been investigating how would this type of world will work but I haven't gotten how. So What I wanted to get was how they would exist in a real world where people deal with the monsters using science and how that would affect their evolution.

Comment: Hello and welcome to worldbuilding. As it stands your question needs more focus. You should be the one who designs your world and its creatures, and ask specific questions about specific things. We can't invent all the creatures for you.

Comment: How can we know the difference between an ordinary fierce animal and a monster? Can you draw a sketch of these monsters - what do they look like?

Comment: Monsters do exist in real-life. There used to be many more, but we tended to use our big, scary brains to hunt them down, kill them (and their children) with nothing more than stone-tipped spears, and then eat them. Ask any smilodon.

Comment: "Monster is a relative term! To a canary, a cat is a monster" - Henry Wu, the one who gives you Jurassic park.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest rephrasing your question. Its filled with "certainly maybe's" that make reading it more difficult. I would also suggest more detail for the monsters you want.

That said, what about a nice Grizzly Bear? These literal monsters can take modern shotgunshots to the face and only be dazed. Strong enough to pulverize your bones, fast enough to outrun you, stealthy enough to catch you off-guard, can climb better than us and heavy enough to crush us.

Or what about Hippo's and Elephants. Big, temperamental creatures. Elephants will in a good mood warn you they are there so you dont get in trample range, or if in a bad mood wait for you to get close and murder you. Hippo's are fast and more territorial, able to run fast on land and will not warn you before biting you practically in half.

Or lets assume part of the dinosaurs survived, and that plate tectonics eventually re-merged the continents after mamals had evolved enough to produce humans. A nice T-Rex should count as a monster right? Although climate changes would likely have made T-Rex's smaller to survive.

Comment: I changed the text like you said I hope you can get a better understanding of it now, I explain in the edit everything btw.